# Android - Dual ListViews Fragments on Android UI

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, android-fragments

I'm new to android development, and I have doubts about working with fragments.

I have to build an App that runs 2 ListViews on the same screen, but the list on the right depends on what I select in the list on the left. I've looked through all the tutorials and samples about the working with Fragments, and I haven't found a way to do that succesfully.

I want to do it in a way that I retrieve the data for the right side from an XML, so I don't have to build all the interfaces for that list one by one, just to have a template List and populate it with the corresponding data.

Any thoughts about how to do that?

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question. How exactly you want the second listview to react to selections in first one?

Comment: its like a category list, the first listview, and the second list are sub-categories of each one of the first list, it's problably something simple but i cant figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use callback mechanism in the parent activity and maintain the references of both the fragments, just have a plain interface in the fragment which is implemented by the activity.

Call the callback in the fragment when the selection changes in the first, and communicate the same to the second fragment through the activity. You can check out the Contacts app implementation in tablet mode for the main Contacts list and Contact detail screen.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity